# Unicode character U+273F rendered as a cherry blossom in browser but not in applications

Tags: macos, font, unicode

I would like to copy/paste the unicode character [U+273F (black florette)](https://graphemica.com/%E2%9C%BF).

Whenever I see it in my browser it looks like a cherry blossom:

[image: Unicode character U+273F rendered as a cherry blossom shape]

However, whenever I copy/paste it into an app, I get a daisy shape instead of the cherryblossom shape like so:

[image: Unicode character U+273F rendered as a daisy shape]

How can I get unicode character U+273F to be rendered as a cherry blossom shape in various applications (such as Pages, Notes, TextEdit, etc) on my mac?

I've tried using various fonts already installed on my mac, and they don't render the cherry blossom shape. When looking online at [the other fonts available to me, they render it in the daisy form](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/273f/fontsupport.htm). Do I have to shell out money for a special proprietary font just to render this character the way I want?

Comment: What url gives you the cherry blossom?

Comment: Almost any when searching the character "✿". The first link in the question displays the symbol as the cherry blossom -- I actually screen shotted said website to get the cherry blossom image. Also I use Firefox as my default browser, I'm not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch to a font used for Chinese, Japanese, or Korean to get that form of the `273F` character.  Check the Font Variation pane in [Character Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/10.14/mac/10.14) for that unicode value to see which ones on your machine will do it.

[image]